# Routing POST with Query Parameters in MVC Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a Web Apì project, I would like to use something like:

POST/mycontroller/1

but also POST/mycontroller/1?user=john

It is easy with GET because the framework routes correctly to each function. However, when I use POST, it does not work. I have 2 POST functions in the same controller. For example:

```
void Post(int id, string content)
```

and

```
void Post(int id, string content, string user)
```

I would hope when I call POST/mycontroller/1?user=john, the framework routes to Post(int id, string content, string user)

I know that I can use binding models, doing a model class and one unique POST function, but it is a mess because I have many functions and I would like to be able to use the query parameters to route the correct function.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try declaring parameter with [FromBody] and [FromUri] attribute like this:

```
    public string Post(int id, [FromBody]string content, [FromUri] string user)
    {
        return "content = " + content + "user = " + user;
    }
```

With above code I was able to call

`/Test/1?user=Ryan`

Request body

"Test Body"

and the result is:

"content = Test Bodyuser = Ryan"

Hope this helps.